# Access is denied. Check credentials and try again, Microsoft graph API, update profile picture

Tags: reactjs, typescript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

```
public updatePhoto = (img) => {
    let body = img ;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory
        .getClient()
        .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
          client
            .api(
              `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/foo@foocompany.com/photo/$value`
            )
            .patch(body)
            .then((response) => {
              resolve(response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              reject(error);
            });
        });
    });
  };
```

The above is my code to call the Microsoft Graph API in order to update the profile photo of a user. I basically call the API with a BLOB of the picture needed to update. Now, I keep getting the error "Access denied". I'm pretty sure I have the credentials necessary to make requests. Can somebody help me?

the below code is a function that converts the image to a blob and passes it to the graph API for uploading.

```
htmlToImage.toBlob(document.getElementById('image_container'))
  .then( (blob)=>this.updatePhoto(blob))
```

Answer (score 0):

because when you get that api , you forgot send authentication.

=> example :

```
 const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer EwAoA8l6BAAU ... 7PqHGsykYj7A0XqHCjbKKgWSkcAg==' <=== important
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
```

you are missing this:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer EwAoA8l6BAAU ... 7PqHGsykYj7A0XqHCjbKKgWSkcAg=='
```

to know who you are

Comment: When passing binary data to the Microsoft graph API, should I pass the info as a BLOB or base64?